# How to install TestNG in eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, testng

I am trying to install TestNG (which I have never used before) in eclipse Kepler (4.3). I've tried to follow the directions provided on the TestNG site (http://testng.org/doc/download.html), but they do not work. The link (http://beust.com/eclipse/) just takes me to a page with a jar file. My experience is that when you use the installer within eclipse, it expects to be provided with a "p2" repository site. If I try to set up a site with the address provided, it fails.

On a related note, do I need to install TestNG as something additional (outside eclipse), or is the eclipse plug-in sufficient?

Answer (score 14):

It is working fine on my machine. I just installed TestNG on my eclipse by following the steps below:

1. Click on Help > Install New software
2. Add the link http://beust.com/eclipse in Work with text box as shown below.
   [image]
3. TestNG feature will be shown, expand the tree node then verify the version.
4. Tick the check box of TestNG
5. Click on Next button then Finish button.

I guess you enter wrong software update site. Remove the **/** and extra spaces around the link "http://beust.com/eclipse/" then try.

Nothing to install outside eclipse.

Comment: The current update site is not working. Here is the URL which lists all the available TestNG plugins for Eclipse - http://beust.com/eclipse-old/

Comment: solution by @Ripon Al Wasim as below is working fine.  Above solution doesn't work anymore

Comment: Thanks vikramvi. It's my pleasure to hear

Answer (score 8):

TestNG can also be installed in Eclipse by using "**Eclipse Marketplace...**" Below are the steps:

1. Open eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...
3. Do search for TestNG (Type the text TestNG in Find text box > Click Go button)
4. After searching: Click Install button at TestNG for Eclipse area
5. Follow the further instructions by eclipse

After successful installation: Go to **Window -> Preferences**. TestNG is enlisted at the left panel in pop-up.

Answer (score 2):

Download Testng.jar and add testng jar as external-lib in eclipse. Eclipse will identify the testng.

Comment: This is not the installation of TestNG eclipse plugin. This jar is for TestNG Java API support.

Comment: TestNG installation is required in eclipse to run/execute the test by using TestNG

Answer (score 0):

Currently, TestNG is not available at https://beust.com/eclipse

To install TestNG in Eclipse version – 2019-03 or above, You can follow these steps:

1. Go to Window > Install New Software.
2. Enter `https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/<TestNG Version>` Refer to this site for TestNG Version: https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/
3. Select TestNG Options and Accept the agreement. Once you complete the process, TestNG will get installed.

Reference: https://testng.org/doc/download.html