# Maven Plugins for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

i tried to install maven into eclipse using  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases this link.And this is giving error,So

What is the latest maven link for maven installation into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/

just drag and drop the install button into your eclipse(juno or kepler) it should work.

you can read more about it here in the maven official website

http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html

Comment: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg02654.html please follow the instructions given there

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22344123/1391924. Remove spaces before and after the update site. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>