# Installation issues on TestNG?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng

I have tried to install TestNG in eclipse Help--> Install new software http://beust.com/eclipse

I am getting following error:

> Unable to connect repository http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml

So I have downloaded testng-6.8.6beta.zip and imported those jars in Build Path and added Junit 4 library.

Still when I click Run As in the class (Test case) it does not show me Run As TestNG, shows only java application.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Which version of eclipse do you have?

Comment: use older version of testng and all will be ok.

Comment: Installed from this repository 30min ago. Worked fine. Check your network connection.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22328610/5229380 Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666735/5229380

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

`Open Eclipse -> Help -> Eclipse Marketplace.`

and trying installing testNG plugin after searching it.

Comment: Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200 .. I dont have Marketplace option

Comment: Even when I am trying to user Eclipse Marketplace it says: "Cannot open Eclipse marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace location:
Connection failed" Even my internet connection is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Open eclipse
Help > Install new software
Enter the update site URL in "Work with:" http://beust.com/eclipse/6.9.12
Click on ok

Edit:
Just click on http://beust.com/eclipse - it'll show you all the versions available.

Then Add the URL to work with as http://beust.com/eclipse/version_number (like the example given above)