# What is the equivalent of Nunit in Java for Eclipse?

Tags: java, automation, cross-browser, nunit

I used to test an application using VS & NUnit and NUnit provided this interface which had all my tests listed under each browser. I had a selenium grid setup to run different browsers. 
Nunit allowed me to run single test in individual browser or all test in one browser. It was really very useful. Now I am testing an app using Java and Selenium. I am wondering if there is a plugin like Nunit for eclipse so I can run all my tests using specific browser one by one. Any advice is greatly appreciated :) . Thanks

Comment: Well, there's JUnit.

Comment: ya I am running tests using Junit and the report at the end is great but can it be set up like Nunit? with Nunit UI all your tests get grouped with browsers I am not able to do that with Junit :(.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use `JUnit` and `Selenium WebDriver` to acceptance test websites

We scratched the idea though, because i (and my other co-workers) had a tendency to overcomplicate the 'point-and-click' automatic acceptance tests, to the point where they were not reliable anymore (we had some huge flow-tests that caused these issues). Now we currently only smoketest `HTML` pages now, using `HtmlUnit` (more or less)

Comment: fair enough! I am just building my framework so just trying to find the best approach... thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: If you want a "point-and-click" test, i would suggest just using `Selenium WebDriver`(i think its called selenium2), and just use plain old `JUnit` (test framework). `HtmlUnit` is more of a string-matcher (based on a url's source code), so no browser driver is needed. It's a bit more basic, but can do what one might need for basic smoke tests.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of NUnit is TestNG or JUnit in Java. You can install TestNG in Eclipse by following the URL:

[How to install TestNG in eclipse Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328610/how-to-install-testng-in-eclipse-kepler)