# Not able to find TestNG options in eclipse after plugin installation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse

I am using eclipse kepler and I installed plugin for testNG as:
Help --> Install New Software --> http://beust.com/eclipse

After the installation, I can't find the TestNG options in eclipse. I even changed my jdk from 1.6 to 1.7 in java compiler and eclipse.ini

Please suggest.

Comment: try by installing once from help>>market place .

Comment: i tried installing plugin from beust.com/eclipse-old and I was able to see TestNG now. So i could create my TestNG clas. However, now I am not able to get RunAs --> testNg option.

Comment: Changed my jre 6 to 7, changed jdk 1.6 to 1.7 since the testng jar i was using was 1.7 compatible. Installed testNG 6.8.22 (older version) and everything worked fine. After running the test case, it gave me jcommander error for which I included jCommander jar.

Comment: @zenith, could you share the exception stack trace of the jcommander error, i suspect there is classpath issue at your project

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22328610/5229380

refer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666735/5229380

Answer (score 2):

there should be something in the "Error Log" view (navigate to "Window" on the top level menu -> Show View -> Error Log), could you paste the relate errors here to help diagnose the issue.

thanks